# ImageButton jumps when visibility is GONE

Tags: android, xml, android-relativelayout

I have a search layout in my app.

In that layout, I have 2 objects that sit at the same place and look exactly the same.

One is `autoCompleteTextView` and the other is `EditText`.

Based on the button that a user clicks it changes the visibility of these objects by using `setVisibility(View.GONE)/setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`.

In my default scenario, an `ImageButton` object is placed in my xml to the end of the `EditText`.
However, when the user clicks to use the `autoCompleteTextView` the `ImageButton` jumps to some other location.

Since all of the `ImageButtons/EditText/autoCompleteTextView` are placed inside a RelativeLayout, I tried to fix the position of the `ImageButton` programmatically by using:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_END, R.id.relativeLayout);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, R.id.relativeLayout);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, R.id.relativeLayout);
ib_Clear.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Where my xml is:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="66dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spi_method">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/ATV_Search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/et_rounded"
        android:dropDownHeight="100dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/assistant"
        android:hint="@string/ActivitySearchItems_Search"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:paddingStart="56dp"
        android:paddingEnd="64dp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorGray"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Et_Search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/et_rounded"
        android:fontFamily="@font/assistant"
        android:hint="@string/ActivitySearchItems_Search"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:paddingStart="56dp"
        android:paddingEnd="64dp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorGray"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Ib_Clear"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/Et_Search"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_cancel" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Ib_Search"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/Et_Search"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_Items_search" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Is there any other way that I can keep the `Ib_Clear ImageButton` in its position even when I set the `Et_Search` to be GONE? I also couldnt find a way to add margin in the settings.

Thank you

Comment: Use `ConstraintLayout` and create a horizontal view chain. `RelativeLayout` cannot handle when anchor views are being removed.

Answer (score 0):

Surround the view that you want to hide with a Frame Layout in the XML file such that Frame layout will be the parent of the view that you want to hide. Then just hide the visibility of the view as currently you are doing and it so won't affect the jumping of view.

Answer (score 0):

try using constraint layout,refer this link to learn more https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spi_method">
    
        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/ATV_Search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/apple"
            android:dropDownHeight="100dp"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/Ib_Clear"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Ib_Search"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Et_Search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/alto"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/Ib_Clear"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Ib_Search"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/Ib_Clear"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@id/Et_Search"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@color/attachment_icon_pdf"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/ATV_Search" />
    
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/Ib_Search"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignStart="@id/Et_Search"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

why not change the visibility to INVISIBLE instead of GONE if you just want to hide the view (and retain the position of everything else ?)

> INVISIBLE:
>
> This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout
> purposes.
>
> GONE:
>
> This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout
> purposes.